# Does oAuth 2.0 protect against token recipient confusion?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I know OAuth is not supposed to be used for authentication, but is often used for that purpose anyway. I am trying to understand how this relates to the following attack scenarios (token recipient confusion):

1) A malicious client connects to a honest resource owner; the malicious client connects to another client and impersonates the resource owner at that client

2) A malicious resource owner obtains a token for a client that the resource owner is allowed to access, and than uses that token to authorise himself at a client that he is not allowed to access.

Does oAuth 2 protects against these scenarios? Does it matter, in either scenario, if the authorization code grant flow or the implicit grant flow is used?

Of course, OpenID connect does protect against both attack scenarios, but I'm wondering about basic OAuth 2.0 now.

Comment: The scenarios you describe don't exist. A resource owner does not connect to a client, nor does a client connect to another client. A client connects to a resource owner. Also a resource owner does not obtain a token; a client does.

Comment: @Tom 1) "A resource owner does not connect to a client": Fixed. 2) "nor does a client connect to another client." Of course a malicious client might (in the role of resource owner). 3) "Also a resource owner does not obtain a token; a client does." If the flow passes through the browser, the resource owner might obtain the token, right?